# This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

when i click on the hrefs the page takes time to redirect but it doesn't at the end, it gives a message that the page is not working.

i run this project on localhost and the links used to work before. bewlow is the code snippet for the navbar

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- 6 -->
    <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a> </li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="/composePost">+</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and here is the code in my app.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home')
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about')
})

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.get('/composePost', (req, res) => {
  res.send('compose')
})
```

Comment: can you post all the code of  your `app.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

I do the same, and it works.
Have you enter the correct server port?
mine is: localhost:3000/somthing, I mean, is literally the same code

```
const app = express();

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});
```

Maybe the problem, is that you view is in a folder, but you are not specifying it, the is would be:

```
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('folder/about');
});
```

Maybe you are not definening the layout correctly.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: regarding the port, the views folder and the layouts all are fine. i double checked. it was perfect before something went wrong and i'm not sure what was it. and my code is too long to post.

Comment: Are you running the right way your code?. The correct ñath to index.js?

Comment: what do you mean? running the js file on console?

Comment: yes, exactly, on console. If you are running the exact path of index.js